# I want to summarize http status by date with amazon athena

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have access logs in Athena like this.

```
time                  hostname    user_agent      http_status  col_0    col_1     col_2    col_3
2018-06-01T10:00:00   host01      Mozilla/5.0     200          2018     6         1        10
2019-06-01T10:00:00   host01      Mozilla/5.0     200          2019     6         1        10
2020-06-01T10:00:00   host01      Mozilla/5.0     404          2020     6         1        10
2021-06-08T10:00:00   host01      Mozilla/5.0     404          2021     6         8        10
2021-06-09T10:00:00   host01      Mozilla/5.0     200          2021     6         9        10
2021-06-10T10:00:00   host01      Mozilla/5.0     404          2021     6         10        10
2021-06-10T11:00:00   host01      Mozilla/5.0     503          2021     6         10        11
2021-06-11T10:00:00   host01      Mozilla/5.0     200          2021     6         11        10
2021-06-12T10:00:00   host01      Mozilla/5.0     503          2021     6         12        10
2021-06-13T10:00:00   host01      Mozilla/5.0     200          2021     6         13        10
2021-06-14T10:00:00   host01      Mozilla/5.0     404          2021     6         14        10
2021-06-15T10:00:00   host01      Mozilla/5.0     200          2021     6         15        10
2021-06-15T11:00:00   host01      Mozilla/5.0     503          2021     6         15        11
```

I would like to count the http status by date.
At that time, it is necessary to display the data for one week from now.

```
date        status_40x  status_50x
2021-06-09  0           0
2021-06-10  1           1
2021-06-11  0           0
2021-06-12  0           1
2021-06-13  0           0
2021-06-14  1           0
2021-06-15  0           1
```

How do I make a sql query?

The types are ...

```
time (string) 
hostname (string) 
user_agent (string) 
http_status (string) 
col_0 (string)(Partitioned) 
col_1 (string)(Partitioned) 
col_2 (string)(Partitioned) 
col_3 (string)(Partitioned)
```

**query**

```
select d.dte, coalesce(status_404, 0), coalesce(status_503, 0)
from (select date '2021-06-09' + n.n * interval '1' day as dte
      from unnest(sequence(0, 6, 1)) as n(n)
     ) d left join
     (select DATE_TRUNC('DAY', cast(from_iso8601_timestamp(time) as date)) as dte, 
             count_if(http_status = '404') AS status_404,
             count_if(http_status = '503') AS status_503
      from access_logs al
      group by dte
     ) al
     on al.dte = d.dte
```

**error**

```
Error running query: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 9:16: Column 'dte' cannot be resolved
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by date (cast your timestamp to date for example) and use [`count_if`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#count_if):

```sql
WITH dataset AS
  (SELECT *
   FROM (VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2018-06-01 10:00:00', 401), 
                (TIMESTAMP '2018-06-01 11:00:00', 400),
                (TIMESTAMP '2018-06-01 10:00:00', 500), 
                (TIMESTAMP '2018-06-02 11:00:00', 400)) AS t (TIME, http_status))

SELECT cast(TIME AS date),
       count_if(http_status BETWEEN 400 AND 499) AS "40x",
       count_if(http_status BETWEEN 500 AND 599) AS "50x"
FROM dataset
GROUP BY cast(TIME AS date)
```

Which gives next results:

| _col0 | 40x | 50x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-06-01 | 2 | 1 |
| 2018-06-02 | 1 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill in dates, you need to generate them.  I think you can use `sequence()` for this:

```
select d.dte, coalesce(status_40x, 0), coalesce(status_50x, 0)
from (select date '2021-06-09' + n.n * interval '1 day') as dte
      from unnest(sequence(0, 6, 1)) n(n)
     ) d left join
     (select cast(time as date) as dte, 
             count_if(http_status BETWEEN 400 AND 499) AS status_40x,
             count_if(http_status BETWEEN 500 AND 599) AS status_50x
      from access_logs al
      group by dte
     ) al
     on al.dte = d.dte;
```

Comment: sorry. I was misunderstanding.